# Keras, predict which player is the strongest (instead of player1 will win?)

Tags: python, keras

Hello I have a dataset that lets me know if player 1 has won:

```
BMI, Temperature, Weight, Player1Win
33.6,17,50.0
26.6,19,31.0
23.3,16,32.1
28.1,20,21.0
43.1,17,33.1
```

I can correctly predict if player 1 will win their game with my model:

```
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.models sequential import
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('winner.csv')
X = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'Player1Win']
Y = df.loc[:, 'Player1Win']

pattern = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_shape=(3,), activation='reread'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100)

_, precision = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print('Precision: %.2f' % (precision*100))
```

But I would like to extend my model, considering all players with this new dataset:

```
BMI, Temperature, Weight, Player1, Player2, Winner
33.6,17,50,Bob,Joe,Bob
26.6,19,31,Nathan,Bob,Bob
23.3,16,32,Bob,Joe,Joe
28.1,20,21,Joe,Bob,Bob
43.1,17,33,Joe,Nathan,Nathan
```

rather than predicting if "player 1 will win", I would like to know if "Bob will win against Nathan". I would like to know what method to use to do this.

I thought of adding 1 column per player, with a 0 and 1 if they won but: 1) it would make a huge matrix 2) it would make false information, because in each match there are only 2 players who play not all.

It would be 3 columns like that:

```
bob,nathan,joe
0,1,0
1,0,0
1,0,0
0,0,1
1,0,0
```

Another question, in my dataset, I have more important parameters than others. Is there a model capable of prioritizing certain variables? In my case, the opponent's name is the most important variable (more than temperature or weight).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really add 3 features as you mentionned because it's a target leakage issue, it mean these data will not be available at the prediction.  (If you already know who wins there is no reason to make predictions right ?).

Therefore I actually see two approachs for this new implementation that aims to predict who wins between each players, including players that are not playing the current game:

1. You can try to keep those 3 news columns as you mentionned but 0
   must correspond to the player which is not in the game. We can
   imagine a modelisation of the relation between the the winner and available
   players that will occurs in the NN with enough data. (I could be
   wrong though, that's why you can try and see if it's converge in a
   good way)
2. You can try to use one model for *each player that are really playing*
   combinations. You would have 3 models if there are 3 players (m1: p1
   vs p2, m2: p1 vs p3, m3: p2 vs p3). Once you have your model trained, you can make a pre-process to select the appropriate model.

Both methods have advantages, the first one is more straightforward and include the possibility to feed a single model in one time with uniformed data but if you have not much data the last approach above **may** be better.

I suppose there could be other approachs more effective for this problem.

About your last question on the feature importance, I suggest you to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65032722/how-to-prioritize-few-neural-network-inputs). That's briefly well explained

Comment: I should have specified, I'm not going to have only 3 players, but rather a hundred. your 1st proposal seems to me the most adapted to my problem. but I ask the question how to make it clear which player has won?

I find myself in this kind of matrix:

P1,P2,P3,WinnerID

The WinnerID columns is the player id that win. what do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how do you want to implement the matrix P1,P2,P3,wID. wID has to be a target and cannot be considered as a feature right ? So it should works with features that I mentioned in the initial reply and target variables has to correspond to which player won (this is wID)

Comment: Yes, that's it, that's the target/what to predict